# Empty jQuery Autocomplete Array in Firefox and Chrome - Works in Safari

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

My php invoicing system uses jQuery autocomplete to lookup a customer's name from my database. The layout of the pages is like this:

invoice.php - contains the variable 'customers' and the php database select script
invoice.js - this contains the jQuery on focus command

In Safari everything works fine. I have used the console to see the variables logged - example (CUSTOMERS – ["Paul Smith"] (1))

But in Chrome and Firefox the console shows: "CUSTOMERS" Array [  ]

My code for invoice.php:

```
var arr_customers = new Array();
<?php $result = mysql_query("select * from customer where breaker='".$_SESSION['breaker_id']."'");?>
<?php $str = ""; $i = 0; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

    arr_customers[<?php echo $i;?>] = new Array();
    arr_customers[<?php echo $i;?>][0] = "<?php echo $row['customer_name']; ?>";
    arr_customers[<?php echo $i;?>][1] = "<?php echo $row['customer_code']; ?>";
    arr_customers[<?php echo $i;?>][2] = "<?php echo $row['address']; ?>";
    arr_customers[<?php echo $i;?>][3] = "<?php echo $row['uid']; ?>";

    <?php if ($i == 0) {
        $str = "'" . $row['customer_name'] . "'";
    } else {
        $str = $str . ",'" . $row['customer_name'] . "'";
    }?>

    <?php $i++;
} ?>
var  customers =<?php echo ("[" . $str . "]") ?>;
```

and for the invoice.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#customer_name").on('focus', function() {
    console.log("CUSTOMERS", customers);
    $( "#customer_name" ).autocomplete({
      source: customers
    });
  });
});
```

I know I should be using prepared statements as well!

Comment: Replaced PHP stuff with JS - http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/eebw53mq/.
Replaced SQL stuff with dummy objects - http://code.runnable.com/VhUySNOv6esHAt8t/32992779-for-php . 

Both seem to work OK. Any chance of a real-world look?

Comment: Thanks @DaveSalomon I've noticed quite a few of my functions don't seem to work in FF/Chrome also. The invoice system's behind a login but I can upload the files to somewhere?

Comment: Could you paste the resulting HTML generated by your PHP? That might shed some light on it. In my tests, it all looks dandy...

Comment: I've pasted into a jsfidde: http://jsfiddle.net/3zpg0fcg/

Comment: Seems fine to me in Chrome 45.0.2454.101m. `var  customers =['Christian Richardson'];` `console.log(customers);`. You will get problems if a customer surname has an `'` in - for example, Danny O'Brien. Maybe that could be having an impact with real data? I'd re-engineer your solution to have an AJAX call fetch all the customer data - at least you're dealing with proper JSON then. (You can fake it using `json_encode` though...)